# Isolated Docker containers and resource limiting

Tags: docker, apparmor

Say I want to build a hosting environment using Docker (so that I can scale up if needed).

I want:

1. Each user to be able to execute arbitrary code and
2. Each user to not see or affect other users

Is this something more concerning Docker, or some other tool like Apparmor?

I want users to be able to run, say, PHP code. If one users gets a lot of hits and is using a lot of cpu, I want it to not affect another user who I've promised a certain amount of cpu usage. Perhaps I'm missing what concept governs this type of thing altogether?

Answer (score 1):

you can limit the memory an cpu usage of dockers using --memory and --cpus flags when you run the docker so users have a maximum amount of resources they are limited to, for all such constraints use the following documentation.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/resource_constraints/